# unable to copy files having space and bracket in filename

Tags: php, file, copy

I am trying to copy the file name "141 (5).jpg" using the copy() function in PHP but I get constantly get hit by

> copy(/home/141 (4).jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/Upload.php on line 506

I tried replacing space with %20 and even url encoded the complete path, but with no success.
Anyone has any idea on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but I would recommend putting the filepath in quotes.

Comment: I am getting the file path in a variable and using that as is here is how: copy($source, $dest)

Comment: That should work, as long as $source and $dest are both strings and you have permissions to access the file.